# Pandas get MySQL create table executable script from dataset

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataset

Is there is a way to generate MySQL executable script to create database tables from a dataset using **pandas**, I know there is the engine connection way, However, I am just trying to get the script for creating the table and inserting all the data.

Comment: To rephrase it, your goal is to generate a python string containing a SQL script to create an SQL table containing all the dataframe data, right ?